# Custom Broadcast receiver not getting invoked in Lollipop

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have declared a receiver in the Manifest, with an intent filter. It is getting invoked correctly in Jellybean but not getting invoked in Lollipop. Is the way a receiver is registered different for Lollipop, is there a need to register it programmatically ? Appreciate your help.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".IPCallConnReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.lib.ip.CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Actually, no. Did you test on other Lollipop devices?

Comment: On which device u tested

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. This would include the `<intent-filter>`, a statement of how you are triggering the broadcast, and how you are checking to see if the broadcast has been received. Providing the implementation of the receiver might help as well.

Comment: I have updated with the declaration in Manifest. I tested it on Moto 2G, just one lollipop device.

Comment: Create a virtual device with Lollipop, and test the app there

Comment: Sure, I will try that.